# Execution order of nested dictionary comprehension

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I'm trying to convert this list:

```
data = [{'A': 123}, {'B': 456}, {'C': 789}]
```

To this dictionary:

```
{'A': 123, 'B': 456, 'C': 789}
```

By using dictionary comprehension:

```
{key: value for key, value in dictionary.items() for dictionary in data}
```

Exception:

```
NameError: name 'dictionary' is not defined
```

Comment: I think you need to swap the for-statements around

Comment: Just do `d = {k: v for _ in data for k, v in _.items()}`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to switch your iteration logic. Default order of iteration inside *dictionary* (or *list*) *comprehension* goes from left to right:

```
>>> data = [{'A': 123}, {'B': 456}, {'C': 789}]

>>> {k: v for d in data for k, v in d.items()}
{'A': 123, 'B': 456, 'C': 789}
```

You can create nested *dictionary comprehension*, *list comprehension* or *generator expression* using `{}`, `[]` and `()` respectively which are the exceptions for the left to right execution order I mentioned earlier. All these operations create new objects, and they execute inside their own scope.